# Почему не работает без квадратных скобок?

Tags: php, html

В Name присвоен checkboxx[] без [] implode не работает, почему? Говорит implode(): Invalid arguments passed

```
     <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"  name ="checkboxx[]" value="<?php echo($ingredient); ?>" id="checkbox<?php echo($id); ?>" checked/>
       <?php 

 if(isset($_POST['button'])){

      $description = $_POST['checkboxx'];

           $val = implode(',', $description);

  $conn ->query("INSERT INTO `Orders` (`name`, `surname`, `address`, ` 
   description`, `telnumber`, `price`) VALUES 
  ('$name','$surname','$address','$val','$tel','$price')");
 $conn->close();

header('Location: Apply.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: Потому, что с квадратными скобками вы на сервере получите массив, а без них - строку. А `implode()` вторым аргументом принимает что? Ну, а если хотите извращений. то можете написать так: `$description = (array)$_POST['checkboxx'];` ))

Comment: Спасибо, implode получает данные внутри инпута с checkboxx[], значение переменной $ingredient

Comment: `implode` вторым аргументом принимать массив.